# VS2013 WebApi2 or MVC5 scaffolding with EF6 error

Tags: asp.net-web-api, asp.net-mvc-5, entity-framework-6

I keep getting "VS2013 has stopped working" error whenever I add controller with scaffolding option

- "Web API 2 Controller with actions, using Entity Framework" or
- "MVC 5 Controller with views, using Entity Framework"

I'm using VS2013 Express for Web MVC5 WebAPI2 EF6.
Any of you got this problem? How can I fix this problem. It's just a simple test project.

Please help. Thanks.

Here is screenshot.
[image: Screenshot]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got a workaround solution from some Microsoft guy.

1. Open a command line with the administrator permission
2. Go to Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0\Common7\IDE
3. Notepad VWDExpress.exe.config
4. Add the following line under `<configuration><runtime>`

   > ```
   > <disableNativeImageLoad>
   >  <assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.Extensions" />
   > </disableNativeImageLoad>
   > ```
5. Save.
6. Open VSExpress, and scaffold it!